# How to iterate through table using columns as variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

EDIT: Classic overthink at play. Thats what no sleep and double hours results in. Thanks for the help! Solution selected below.

I have a table structured like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ##Products(
    [ProductID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,[Item_Code] nvarchar(255) NULL
    ,CustomerNumber int NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What I want to do is use the Item_Code and Customer Number columns of the rows in this list and run them against another table in order to get the MaxDate of each one. Each Row contains a product and customer and I need to get the MaxDate for those so I can know the last time each customer bought a specific product for gap analysis.

Loops are my weakest area in SQL so looking for some help in structuring this.

My outcome needed:
I need to take that existing table and append the MAxDate result as another column to each row. So that the new table would look like so:

```
CREATE TABLE ##Products2(
    [ProductID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,[Item_Code] nvarchar(255) NULL
    ,CustomerNumber int NULL
        ,LastPurchase datetime NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Im close but I cannot seem to get the data pulled into a new table.

Ive tried many other pieces of code but my inexperience in Loops makes it so Im not fully grasping the concept.

Here is what I currently have (Pulled from another post here)

```
declare @RowNum int, @ProductID nvarchar(255), @Name1 nchar(255)

select @ProductID=MAX(ProductID) FROM ##Fact_ProductChurn
Select @RowNum = Count(*) From ##Fact_ProductChurn
WHILE @RowNum > 0
BEGIN   
    select
    @Name1 = PC.cust_num
    from ##Fact_ProductChurn PC
    LEFT JOIN FACT_Orders FO ON PC.cust_num = RTRIM(LTRIM(FO.Cust_num)) 
    INNER JOIN DIM_Products DP ON FO.item = DP.item
    where ProductID = @ProductID

    --THINKING I NEED TO DO SOMETHING HERE TO ADD NEW DATA TO NEW TABLE THEN MOVE ON TO NEXT ROW



    select
    top 1 @ProductID=ProductID
    from ##Fact_ProductChurn
    where ProductID < @ProductID
    order by
    ProductID desc

    set @RowNum = @RowNum - 1
END
```

Comment: Your source table doesn't have a date column, so I don't understand where that information comes from.  Your sample query then mentions tables that aren't in the text.  I'm confused.

Comment: You do not want or need loops here. This is a basic aggregate query. Also, be wary of global temp tables. They are evil.

Comment: From which table you will collect MaxDate for Item_Code and CustomerNumber? and what is the relation between that table with the table ##Products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an imagination for what you may need:

```
select max(LastPurchase ) as LastPurchase ,Item_Code,CustomerNumber
group by Item_Code,CustomerNumber
```

Comment: He stated he is weak in loops , therefore I needed to give example at the same point,

Comment: so, I'll delete it, Thanks @Sean Lange

Comment: I am guessing the OP probably needs a join between a couple of tables but it is impossible to determine from the lack of details they posted. +1 for demonstrating a solid set based solution. :)

Comment: @SeanLange What happened was a simple case of overthinking my solution. Our data where I work is...less than optimally kept within syteline. On top of that, they managed to create far too many layers of complexity on top of that. In most cases, whats needed is needlessly complex. My brain went down that road first instead of taking a step back.

I did just need to rearrange my aggregate to get what I needed.